# Google sheets: separate and sum positive and negative numbers in column with vlookup

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to separate positive and negative numbers in a column and sum them up in 2 different columns based on a vlookup in google sheets.

I tried formulas like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(sumif($A$2:$A, ">0"&E2,$B$2:$B))

=ArrayFormula(sumif($A$2:$A, "<0"&E2,$B$2:$B))
```

But unfortunately they didn't work quite well.
(Please see an example attached.)

[image]

Comment: Can you explain "they didn't work quite well"?

Comment: yes, the outcome is not right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify only one criterion in the `SUMIF` formula. So in `G2` cell you sum all that is greater as `08858`.

Use `SUMIFS` instead:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,B:B,">0",A:A,E2)
```

[image]

---

**Reference:**

- [`SUMIFS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496?hl=en)